# get dom element by attribute in ionic 4

Tags: angular7, ionic4, getattribute

I'm upgrading my Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4.

I'm working google maps and markers. I added few buttons in `infoWindow` and declared an attirbute `data-id`. Now I want to get these buttons using this attribute `data-id`

Here's the related code:

```
let content = '<b>' + locations[i].name + '</b><br/>' + locations[i].street + "<br/>";
content += "<button id='edit-customer-" + i + "' class='edit-customer button button-md button-default-secondary button-default-md' ion-button data-id='" + locations[i].id + "'>Editar</button>";
content += "<button id='order-customer-" + i + "' class='order-customer button button-md button-default-secondary button-default-md' ion-button data-id='" + locations[i].id + "'>Pedido</button>";
content += "<button id='event-customer-" + i + "' class='event-customer button button-md button-default-secondary button-default-md' ion-button data-id='" + locations[i].id + "'>Evento</button>";
infowindow.setContent(content);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'domready', () => {
let infoWindow = infowindow;
document.getElementById('edit-customer-' + i).addEventListener('click', (event) => {
var targetElement = (<HTMLButtonElement>event.target || event.srcElement);
var id = targetElement.getAttribute("data-id"); //getAttribute shows syntax error 'Property "getAttribute" does not exist on type "EventTarget"'
infoWindow.close();
me.editCustomer(id);
});
});
```

`var id = targetElement.getAttribute("data-id");`

syntax error 'Property **getAttribute** does not exist on type **EventTarget**'

Am I doing something wrong?
Any alternate way to getAttribute?

Comment: I guess you can use "Viewchild" method.

Comment: @Marco Chavez yeah thanks. How can i forget.